# How to use warp-tls instead of warp with scotty?

Tags: haskell, scotty, haskell-warp

I need to start my scotty application with warp-tls instead of plain warp server but is seems running warp is hardwired in scotty's source code. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: You can use the function `scottyApp` instead of `scotty` to get a WAI `Application`. From there it's Scotty independent and you can pass it to warp's `runTLS` function.

Comment: `\p s -> run p =<< scottyApp s` = `scotty` :)

Comment: /me stupid If you lift your comment into an answer I will accept it :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `scottyApp` function instead of `scotty`, to get a WAI `Application` which you can pass to warp's `runTLS`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Network.Wai.Handler.WarpTLS (runTLS, tlsSettings)
import Network.Wai.Handler.Warp (defaultSettings, setPort)
import Network.Wai.Middleware.RequestLogger (logStdoutDev)
import Web.Scotty

main :: IO ()
main = do
    let tlsConfig = tlsSettings "your.crt" "your.key"
        config    = setPort 3443 defaultSettings
    waiApp <- scottyApp $ do
        get "/"      (text "hello")
        get "/hello" (text "hello again")
    runTLS tlsConfig config (logStdoutDev waiApp)
```